# Return a Spring Bean with every Ajax call

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I've a spring bean with 3 Maps all of which are to be populated incrementally

- First Map is a project list
- Second Map is a team members list
- Third Map is a hobby for team member list

All the maps are mapped to `<form:select>` and `<form:options>` on the JSP

When the page is loaded only the **first map** is populated
on the **onchange** event of first map, I need to populate the **second map** in the bean
and similarly on the onchange event of second map, I need to populate the **third map** in the bean. Is there a way to do this using Ajax??

Clarification:
@Donal: I have a simple JSP page with 3 dropdowns corresponding to 3 maps stored in my `commandBean`. So when the page loads for the first time only the first map and hence the first dropdown is populated. Now whenever the user selects anything out of the first dropdown, I need to send the same commandbean back with the values of the first dropdown and get the values for the second map and hence the second dropdown and so forth for the 3rd dropdown as well. For each dropdown I 've got 3 maps and 3 variables for storing the selected values. Now I want to understand if this is possible using Ajax. I hope this clarifies whatever you need to know. Thanx

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to know in your own mind and then reword the question. Spring MVC is a server-side technology, AJAX is a client-side technology, and you need to work out whether the problem you're dealing with is incomplete data from a request or incorrect piecing together of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitly doable. You should look into use some client-side javascript library, like [jquery](http://jquery.com/). It makes the AJAX part [much easier](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

On the server, you should look at creating a mapping that returns JSON data instead of HTML since that is easier to work into javascript and AJAX. Look at [`@ResponseBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) and the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.

Here is an old but pretty good [blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) you can look at.